# How to save php socket resource in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sockets

I am creating a socket in php with socket_create and would like to store the received socket in a database (to access from other php code).
However the socket is of type 'resource'. How can I store this in mysql ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You cannot store a resource / socket in database.

Instead, you'd have to store the informations that would allow you to re-create it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, still need to figure out how to do that. Because recreating a socket will (what I think) drop the previous connection.