# Chat application using websockets

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I have been able to use Websockets to create a chat application between users using https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets.

What the server does is stores all the created socket object variables in an array when each user connects to the socket. So, ultimately he creates an array which has info regarding all users with the socket object. And he loops through the array each time to retrieve the object of a user so that message can be sent to the respective socket.

This will be fine for small amount of users. But how do we handle huge amounts of users? I thought of storing socket objects in DB but then I came across this: [How to save php socket resource in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249616/how-to-save-php-socket-resource-in-database)

Which says "Sockets have to be recreated and cannot be stored in DB".

So, is there any better option rather than recreating? And if I have to recreate the socket, how do I do it using the PHP-Websockets library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket cannot be saved on disk because it's existing connection. If you destroy the live object, the connection is closed and the user is disconnected.

First I want to remind you, that memory and CPU might not be much of a concern. Node.js interpreter is actually surprisingly fast and WebSocket object hardly takes much memory. You will face other issues first, such as bandwidth problems, too many open connections etc.

Possible tweaks I can think of:

#### Multithreading - spawn child processes

You can share sockets between node.js processes though, which is described here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_server_object

I cannot guarantee this will improve performance but it allows you to handle input from different users in parallel. I also don't know if WebSockets do support this, but I think so.

#### Reducing socket overhead

This is important to remember - you can't store the socket object on disk, but you can store most of other stuff. The socket object hardly takes significant amount of memory but if you store other info about user, it might slow you down. Redundant information should be stored in backend provided by database or something like that.

#### Native core

If you still encounter problems, you can write C/C++ native multithreaded core for your chat and let it do the heavy operations, such as looping through sockets and sending them messages. Have this core connected to Node.js server where your logic will be. Also not that you can write native plugins for Node.js.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I will wait for a bit more time and will accept your answer if there is nothing better but one question. (Just a scenario)
Say a  company like Facebook does this and have millions of users online at the same time. And all their socket info are stored in a array in the same server. So, how will there be efficiency in searching for the socket object? Is there something like indexing the array to deal with this scenario? I am not worried about the storage memory it takes but the time it takes to search through the array.

Comment: They are hardly using single server for the task. You can set up a grid of servers around the globe which only share the information they need. Also, they hardly loop through some array, that's not the way to handle this. When client requests unread messages, they are fetched from database and sent to him. If he's just connected he is probably still polling some database because as I said, he's probably not connected to the same server.

Comment: I thought about it a little more, and if I was asked to deal with this in node JS, I'd run several processes, each handling X sockets. I'd use similar algorithm minecraft uses to store blocks. There are 16x16 chunks of data, and you first calculate block chunk (coordinates/16. rounded up) and then loop the chunk for specific block.

Comment: Hmm.. got you.. But if you split it into processes, the server still has to check sockets in every process till it finds the corresponding user's socket object. This might be an improvement but still is a bit ineffective. Or may be do like what Hadoop does? Like send search request to all processes parallel and this makes search faster? May be?

Comment: @vignesh No, I was talking about such multitasking, where user ID contains information about the thread he's running in. Thinking about this problem is indeed interesting, but you'll see it does not have real-life application.

Comment: hmm.. maybe but I wonder what happens if Facebook or big giants uses Websockets. I think Google uses it already..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95056/discussion-between-tomas-zato-and-vignesh).

Answer (score 0):

Use unique user_ids or device_ids. For example, session id, and store thays to DB. Than, send user_id when subscribing to events, and send messages only to that user.

Comment: Yes. But the problem is how will I "send message to that user" without knowing their socket info? Is there any way?

Comment: When client connects to server, he *must* emit new event ("register" for example) with user_id in payload. Server handle this event, store user_id in database, and connect socket to user_id. Socket info - in memory all time. After server restarts, client will be disconnected in any way, so socket will be destroyed - there is no reason for saving socket handler in database.

Comment: Any connected user emit "register" event after connecting, sou you have info about *all* connected users and can send message to any of them.

Comment: So, does this mean that storing socket objects in arrays are sensible? Wont there be any impact (say Facebook uses websockets, its websocket server will be flooded with array of info. So, each time you have to search through the array for the socket object of respective user.) I have already done the register event and storing uid part though.